# Handling search parameters URL PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I am wondering if I would be able to get some advice.

I am trying to build a search for my site and I want to link to be reusable so it can be sent as a link to someone else to see the same results.

The problem I have is that there is the possibility to have 100s of parameters for this search, so I dont think a GET requests in the URL are the right way to go.

I was thinking of the possibility of creating a JSON file that saves the parameters in the search and to give it a specific name say "qwer-eweq-qwe" then the URL link could be [www.mysite.com/qwer-eweq-qwe](http://www.mysite.com/qwer-eweq-qwe)

Then once a user would navigate to the URL it would then read the JSON file and pull the correct parameters.

Is there any other ways I could do this? Can seem to find too much online. any pointers would be very helpful

Thanks,

Richard

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) would you please show us what you tried ?

Comment: Hello @Dlk, I havent tried anything yet.  I am just trying to work out the best way to approach this - so i am asking for some advice for possible routes to explore and if my current thoughts of saving a json file will work.

Comment: _"the possibility to have 100s of parameters"_ This makes me think/hope you are using a database. Instead of using a file, why not store the query in that same database, along with an ID or Unique URL slug, instead of saving it to a file? Files are fine for small/quick & dirty projects, but as it gets bigger, it will be messy and hard to maintain

Comment: In addition to @blex you could cache your search result using Redis. When you want to share that search result with someone else you could send a link with a cache key for that search result. And then when that someone makes a request using that link you would use that GET parameter which is Redis cache key and retrieve the search result from Redis and display it.

Comment: @blex I am using a database - i was thinking about this route also. Was a little unsure how to actually store the parameters. Something like the unique key with a text field storing the information I need say in JSON format?

Comment: @blex - Sorry I just thought of how to store it - I will be using a store proc to return the results so I just have to store the store proc call.  Thanks - I will post my CODE here once ive got it built

Comment: @glassrichard1990 Sure, that would work

Answer (score 0):

With so many parameters, please, consider switching way of dealing with it.

An idea would be to use a filter system. One POST method would create a filter with a set of parameters in body (either raw or JSON, does not matter).

`POST /filter`

The call would create (or not, if already exists) a filter.
The call would return a filter ID that you can use to search by fixed parameters:

`GET /search/:filterid`

That way, you even can manage cache limitations depending on filters, by invalidating those if needed.

Comment: have you any examples or something to read? - I know the way I am thinking about will work but fells like there should be a different way of putting it together.  I do want the function of saving a users search criteria so its also something I have to think about

Comment: Most of the time, it heavily depends on the application.  Filter-based searches always relies on unique filters, and to ensure that, you'll need an ID for the filter.


Note that the ID can be anything, and you can also provide human-readable strings, like most of code hostings platforms does aka "InfamousLazyHotDog" or such stuff. That allows both the code (by having an unique ID for the filter) and the user (by having an easily recognizable URI) to be on the same search filter and to share it.


tl;dr : it's the right way to do but remember about POST uses to create a filter if needed